# How do I follow part of this simple proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (a_n b_n) = a b$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**I'm working through some analysis textbooks on my own, so I don't want the full answer. I'm only looking for a [hint](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11258/93114) on this problem.**

In Rosenlicht's *Introduction to Analysis*, he proves, in a few short steps, that if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n = b$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (a_n b_n) = a b$. Although I'm able to follow parts of the proof, there's one nexus I'm having trouble understanding. His steps (up until I get stuck) are:

1. Start with the fact that all convergent sequences are bounded to get a number $M > 0$ such that $|a_n| < M$ and $|b_n| < M$.

   **My work:** This is saying that the sequences of points $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are contained in the open ball centered at 0 with radius $M$.

   I understand this because if I pick any $\epsilon > 0$, the fact that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ means that $\exists N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $|a - a_n|< \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$. Then $\{a_n\}$ is contained in the closed ball of radius $r_a = \max\{\epsilon, |a - a_1|, |a - a_2|, \dots, |a - a_N|\}$ centered at $a$. The same holds true for $\{b_n\}$ and $b$, which gives me some $r_b$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

   Then, I can pick $r = \max\{d(0, a)+r_a, \ d(0, b)+r_b\} = \max\{|a|+r_a, \ |b|+r_b\}$ so all points in $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ the closed ball centered at 0 with radius $r \geq 0$. I can then pick some real number $M > r$, which completes this step of the proof.
2. Since a closed ball is a closed set, the preceding theorem implies $|a|, |b| \leq M$.

   **My work:** This is the step I don't understand. The preceding theorem states that if $S$ is a subset of the metric space $E$, then $S$ is closed if and only iff, whenever $p_1, p_2, \dots, $ is a sequence of points of $S$ that is convergent to $p$ in $E$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} p_n = p \in S$.

   I think this is how this step follows, but I'm not sure. Since the points in $\{a_n\}$ are contained in the closed ball $B_a$ centered at 0 with radius $r^*_a = d(0, a)+r_a = |a| + r_a$, and since an earlier proposition proved that a closed ball is a closed set, we have $a \in B_a$ by the theorem above.

   Since $a$ is in the closed ball centered at 0 with radius $r^*_a$ and by construction, $M > r^*_a$, we know that $a$ is also in the closed ball centered at 0 with radius $M$, so $|a| \leq M$. The same holds true for $|b|$.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Consider the closed ball with radius $M$ and centre $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmm, ok. I must be missing something, because  I used that exact closed ball in my last paragraph and I think it explains the part of the proof I'm trying to explain, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You conclude that $\lvert a\rvert < M$, but that need not hold, you can have equality. I think your problem is that you have confused yourself a bit with the $r_a^\ast$. Just note that $\lvert a_n\rvert < M$ for all $n$ implies $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant M$ for all $n$, that means the $a_n$ all lie in the closed ball with radius $M$ and centre $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, that last $|a| < M$ was a typo, but you're definitely correct in that I may have confused/overcomplicated this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $r_a^*=M $. Other than that, your logic is fine.

Comment: That means I need to exclude the trivial case where $a_n = b_n = 0, \forall n$, because otherwise, $M = r^*_a = 0$, and the proof will break down later because it utilizes $\epsilon / 2M$, right?

Comment: No need. As you wrote in the first part, $M>r $, so $M>0$.